# How to enable headset mode for ALC298 driver on Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro laptop and when I'm plugging my headset, it detects only headphones, but not the mic. [This is what i see in settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfx88.png)

I tried pavucontrol with the [same result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f0ic.png) Only laptop mic is detected.

Also I checked this headset with another laptop (Lenovo 520-IKB) which had Ubuntu 18.04 on board and it works as expected.

After a couple days of searching the internets i found similar questions, the closest one being [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835033/ubuntu-16-04-headset-microphone-not-recognized). I tried setting `options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic` and `options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode` but that didn't fix the issue for me.

Not sure what to do next. Does anyone have ideas what else can i try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: I added

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc298-dell1
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and it worked.

After i posted the question i decided to check out what models can i test in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. I found this information in kernel sources in the `./Documentation/sound/hd-audio/models.rst`.

I was trying models that had "headset" in their names. To be more precise first two were `headset-mic` and `headset-mode` which i have already tried before i posted the question. So i tried the next one which is `dell-headset-multi` and it partially fixed my problem. I was able to choose a headset mode when i plugged in my headset. But headset's mic still didn't work.

Then i decided to try specific alc298 models and added to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` a line with

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc298-dell1
```

and after that my mic started working.

Answer (score 1):

Today 2020.04.29 I have lost my microphone) It suddenly stops working (with and without headset connected). I guess it happend after OS software updates. Switching to the previous Linux headers version was unhelpful

Adding the line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc298-dell1
```

to the end of file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` solved my problems with Xiaomi Notebook Lite 2019 (light) and the following OS:

```
Operating System: KDE neon 5.18
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.69.0
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Kernel Version: 5.3.0-51-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,5 ГиБ
```

This notebook has ALC256 sound card